# BindindSource Filter does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

Please see the following code on a Winform `Load` method:

```
List<CustomersDTO> res = new List<CustomersDTO>();
res = _CustomerBO.GetCustomers();
customerBindingSource.DataSource = res;
customerDataGridView.DataSource = this.customerBindingSource;
customerBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.customerBindingSource;
```

Now I want to filter on Searchbutton but I am not able to see filtered record on screen.

```
customerBindingSource.Filter = "Active = false";
```

I am missing something.. I did reasearch. Can anybody give me exact code example? I read about implementing `IBindingList` but not sure how to do that with my BindingSource..

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to implement `IBindingList`. You can construct a `BindingList` as the DataSource of your `customerBindingSource`. Like This:

```
customerBindingSource.DataSource = new BindingList<CustomersDTO>(res);
```

Comment: Evn though I have added Bindinglist as datasource.. still filter doesnot work. Am I missing something?